# Django attribute of most recent reverse relation

Tags: django

I have two models:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    test_id = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, db_index=True)

class TestResult(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey("Test", to_field="test_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=status_choices)
```

with `status_choices` as an enumeration of tuples of strings.

Some Test objects may have zero related TestResult objects, but most have at least one.

I want to filter Test objects based on their most recent TestResult status.

I have tried this:

```
    queryset = Test.objects.all()
    queryset = queryset.annotate(most_recent_result_pk=Max("testresult__pk"))
    queryset = queryset.annotate(current_status=Subquery(TestResult.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef("most_recent_result")).values("status")[:1]))
```

But I get the error:

> column "u0.status" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an
>   aggregate function LINE 1: ...lts_testresult"."id") AS
>   "most_recent_result_pk", (SELECT U0."status...

I can find the most recent TestResult object fine with the first annotation of the pk, but the second annotation breaks everything. It seems like it ought to be easy to find an attribute of the TestResult object, once its pk is known. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one subquery, without annotating this first:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

queryset = Test.objects.annotate(
    current_status=Subquery(
        TestResult.objects.filter(
            test=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-pk').values('status')[:1])
)
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT test.*,
    (SELECT U0.status
     FROM testresult U0
     WHERE U0.test_id = test.id
     ORDER BY U0.id DESC
     LIMIT 1
    ) AS current_status
FROM test
```

or without subquery:

```
from django.db.models import F, Max

queryset = Test.objects.annotate(
    max_testresult=Max('testresult__test__testresult__pk')
).filter(
    testresult__pk=F('max_testresult')
).annotate(
    current_status=F('testresult__status')
)
```

That being said, ordering by primary key is *not* a good idea to retrieve the latest object. You can see primary keys as "blackboxes" that simply hold a value to refer to it.

It is often better to use a column that stores the timestamp:

```
class TestResult(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey("Test", to_field="test_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=status_choices)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and then query with:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

queryset = Test.objects.annotate(
    current_status=Subquery(
        TestResult.objects.filter(
            test=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-created').values('status')[:1])
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had done basically this earlier, however the order_by increased query time dramatically. I made two separate annotations in the hopes that I could bypass the order_by and just specify the result directly. I'm not sure what other options I have apart from redesigning my database.

Comment: @my_friend_tux: well I don't see a way to bypass it. But even if you somehow would be able to do that, it would mean another join and a lookup, which will likely result in approximately the same performance.

Comment: @my_friend_tux: there is one without `ORDER BY`, but I doubt that this will improve performance (significantly).